# Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'System.Func<int>'

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm creating a task of calling a function CountPixels as shown below

```
Task<int> task1 = new Task<int>(()=>{CountPixels(croppedBitmap, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));});
```

The code for CountPixels is as follows:

```
private int CountPixels(Bitmap croppedBitmap, Color target_color)
    {
        int height = croppedBitmap.Height;
        int width = croppedBitmap.Width;
        int matches = 0;
        List<int> x1range = new List<int>();
        List<int> y1range = new List<int>();
        for (int y1 = 0; y1 < height; y1++)
        {
            for (int x1 = 0; x1 < width; x1++)
            {
                if (croppedBitmap.GetPixel(x1, y1) == target_color
                {
                    matches++;
                    x1range.Add(x1);
                    y1range.Add(y1);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("before modification : {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        x1range.sort;
        y1range.sort;
        int x1max, y1max;
        x1max = x1range.Count - 1;
        y1max = y1range.Count - 1;
        try
        {
            fruit1.Text = "X1 MIN =  " + x1range[0] + "  X1 MAX =  " + x1range[x1max] + "  Y1 MIN =  " + y1range[0] + "  Y1 MAX =  " + y1range[y1max];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
        return matches;
    }
```

I'm getting an Error at the task1 line:

> Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'System.Func int>'

Please help me out..where am I going wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

It's easy. Don't forget to return the value:

```
Task<int> task1 = new Task<int>(()=> { return CountPixels(croppedBitmap, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255)); });
```

Answer (score 7):

try removing the curly braces in your lambda statement:

```
Task<int> task1 = new Task<int>(()=> CountPixels(croppedBitmap, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255)); );
```

There are [different kinds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) of lamdas, for example this is an *expression lambda* (according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)):

```
(x, y) => x == y
```

It returns the result of the expression.

And this is the *statement lambda*:

```
(x, y) => { return x == y; }
```

So, when you use curly braces you are creating a statement lambda and there is no implicit returning, you have to explicitly use the `return` to return a value.

Answer (score 4):

Try (I've added the return keyword).

```
Task<int> task1 = new Task<int>(()=>{return CountPixels(croppedBitmap, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));})
```

Although CountPixels returns an int you're not returning that int in the task itself.