# How to pass method as parameter in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am learning some advance features of c# in visual studio 2017. where I am trying to pass function as parameter to another function.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();

    myClass.Setup(x =>
    {
        x.Invitation = "Hello {PersonName}, you are invited to our wedding";
        x.PersonName= "John Doe";
    });
    Console.WriteLine(myClass.Call());
    Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

internal class MyClass
{
    string msg = "";
    public MyClass()
    {
        msg = "hello";
    }
    public string Call()
    {
        return msg;
    }

    internal void Setup(Func<string, string> p)
    {
        string Invitation = p("Invitation");
        string PersonName = p("PersonName");
        msg = Invitation.Replace("{PersonName}", PersonName);
    }
}
```

But, I am getting error like:

> Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type
>   'Func'

and

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'GreetingMessage' and no
>   extension method 'GreetingMessage' accepting a first argument of type
>   'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

I am not sure what are errors saying, that I am pritty much new about this thing.

I've also checked the below link to find resolution, but not sure how it will help me.
[Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'System.Func<int>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017485/not-all-code-paths-return-a-value-in-lambda-expression-of-type-system-funcint)

Comment: The first error says your delegate is not returning a value.  If you don't want to return a value, use Action<T> instead of Func<T, T>. .

Comment: @LeoBartkus - you mean to say like this: internal void Setup(Func<string> p) ??

Comment: internal void Setup(Action<string> p)   Func is for when you return a value.